# Create Pivot table in VBA with multiple values by one row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a pivot table that looks like this:

[image: Pivot Effect]

I looked in Microsoft and it only teaches me how to create one column for [Sum of SKU Ship quantity]:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Select  
Range("A1").Select  
Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Deal ID & SKU")  
objField.Orientation = xlRowField  

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("SKU Ship quantity")  
objField.Orientation = xlDataField
```

But this only creates one column for SKU Ship quantity, when I tried to add [GROSS SELL TO (LC)] with the same script, the pivot table just get distorted.
I have several columns to add. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Select
Range("A1").Select
Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=Sheets.Add.Range("A3"))

With objTable
    .PivotFields("Deal ID & SKU").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("SKU Ship quantity").Orientation = xlDataField
    .PivotFields("GROSS SELL TO (LC)").Orientation = xlDataField
    With .DataPivotField
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. May I ask a further question? Now that the pivot table is starting at A1, how can I set this to start at A3 in the pivot table sheet? Thanks.

Comment: The `PivotTableWizard` method has a `TableDestination` argument. See amended code above.